# How to detect when an app or activity starts in Android?

Tags: android, logcat, launching-application

I would like to be able to detect the launch of another app/activity from my service.

I was previously able to do this via inspection of logcat messages, specifically something like:

```
I/ActivityManager: Starting: Intent ... cmp=packagename} from pid xxxx
```

Once I detect this, I would check the packagename for a match.

However, some non AOSP phones such as the Samsung Galaxy S2 with ICS doesn't display this when apps are launched.

Yet, there are apps out there that are able to detect app/activity launches on the Galaxy S2, for example, Smart App Protector. I've looked at the apps permissions and it does request for access to logcat. However, what use is that if the phone doesn't print anything to logcat upon app/activity launches?

What are some possible ways to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add your own log in the activity's onCreate method? Something like: Log.d(TAG, "Activity withName Started");

Comment: I'm trying to detect other apps, not my own apps.

Comment: Why did you down vote me? Since your question was not clear you cannot say that I answered crap. You should have clearly said that you want NOTYOURS apps to log.

Comment: I ask the same question
What did you do in the end?